# PHPExcel Writer object uses huge memory and time outs eventually

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, phpexcel

I am creating a excel sheet using:

1. **Codeigniter 2.2.1**
2. **PHP 5.4.25**
3. **Apache 2.4.7**
4. **XAMPP 1.8.2**
5. **PHPExcel 1.8.0**

I am fetching **35000 rows** (mostly empty) with **79 columns** from database and writing to excel file (Excel5).

It works just fine for 30000 rows with peak memory usage of **1.44GB**,file size 24MB. But when I go for 35000 it times out saying,

**Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1780219904) (tried to allocate 17301483 bytes) in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\ProjectName\application\libraries\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel5\BIFFwriter.php on line 144**

When I am creating PHPExcel object it uses big amount of memory and time outs finally. I have set "**memory_limit= -1**" and "**max_execution_time= 1000**" in php.ini file and tried different cache storage method in PHPExcel.

My algorithm in controller looks like this

```
public function write_controller() {    
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); //-1 for unlimited memory
    $dir = "assets/output/";

    //FIRST CHECK IF PREVIOUS FILE EXISTS OR NOT
    $this->clear_directory($dir);

    // Loading PHPExcel library
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel');
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory');

    $cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_phpTemp;
    $cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '5000MB', 'cacheTime' => '1000'); 

    PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

    //First Create the xls file and then insert rest of the data
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("export")->setDescription("none");

    //activate sheet number 1
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    //Setting font styles
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Arial')->setSize(8)->setBold(false);

    //Setting number format as TEXT
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);

    //Freezing first top row
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');


    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    $row1 = 1;

    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $row1, "Site name");
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $row1, "Vendor_1");
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $row1, "Status");
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $row1, "Easting");
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $row1, "Northing");
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, $row1, "Sector_1");
    .
    .
    .
    //Rest of the 74 columns

    $style = array(
        'alignment' => array(
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER, 
            'vertical' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER)
    );

    $objWorksheet->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($style);

    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

    $saved_location ='assets/output/Piano11.xls'; 
    $objWriter->save($saved_location); 

    //Now reading the saved xls file
    $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();

    $newPHPExcel = $objReader->load($saved_location); 

    $newWorksheet = $newPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    //Now insert rest of the data from Piano table which will come from database
    $table_name = 'piano_test';

    $query = $this->db->get('tbl_piano');

    if (!$query) {
        return false;
    }

    // Fetching the data from table
    $fields = $query->list_fields();

    $row = 2;
    foreach ($query->result() as $data) {
        set_time_limit(0);
        $col = 0;
        foreach ($fields as $field) {
            $newWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $data->$field); //<- This skips leading 0s
            $col++;
        }
        $row++;
    }

    $newobjWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($newPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $newobjWriter->save('assets/output/Piano11.xls');

    echo 'Memory peak usage: <b>'.$this->convert(memory_get_peak_usage(true)).'</b><br/>';
    gc_collect_cycles();//garbage collector
    echo 'inserted.';
}
```

Any solution how can I minimize memory usage & execution time? Or Any other alternative solution? Or Should I change my algorithm?

Comment: Clear memory, calculate amount needed vs clearing what you can and then use a memory_limt http://davidwalsh.name/increase-php-memory-limit-ini_set... These are all i ever need and i deal with geo databases 80+gb.. you would have a memory leak or something. Some times its better to batch this.. Check if your PHP version has a known memory leak as this happens often. Try https://www.airpair.com/php/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size otherwise you might be out of luck.. Its always been an issue to some extend

Comment: As you're creating multiple Writers in this script, you might want to unset each after you've called the save() method for the Writer

Comment: You can see I have set memory limit to -1 which is all possible memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You're using phptemp for caching, but with settings

```
$cacheSettings = array('memoryCacheSize' => '5000MB', 'cacheTime' => '1000');
```

This means that PHPExcel will use 5000MB (5GB) of your PHP memory before its starts to make use of phptemp for caching..... I'd be surprised if you had php.ini max memory settings allowing PHP to use that much memory

You should use a much lower value for `memoryCacheSize`, perhaps `512MB`, which means that PHPExcel will only use 512MB of PHP Memory for caching cell data before it switches to using php://temp

Comment: I have changed and testing it but as you're PHPExcel moderator I'm asking you, what could be possible(or best) caching method for writing excel sheet? On the other hand if execution time & memory is not an issue for me, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: The most efficient caching method in terms of memory is SQLite or SQLite3, but it's slower than some of the other methods.... there really is no such thing as "best" because it's dependent on individual circumstances

Comment: If you're working with large volumes of data, it's also typically a good idea to run the task as a background process, perhaps from the command line rather than as a web request, because you aren't time-constrained in the same way

Comment: Yes I have run this script from Task Scheduler in Windows 7 but no luck!  But finally I managed to export the table into CSV and then convert (with modifications) to Excel5 using PHPExcel.